# why the terminal on mac does not find sdk .net 8 when I already download

Tags: .net

when I run : dotnet --info I got this:

.NET SDKs installed:
No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
No runtimes were found.

Other architectures found:
arm64 [/usr/local/share/dotnet]
registered at [/etc/dotnet/install_location_arm64]

Environment variables:
Not set

global.json file:
Not found

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

thank you for take your time to read my question and answer.

I tried two ways
I run: brew install --cask dotnet
install from: [https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.100-macos-arm64-installer#:~:text=https%3A//download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/cf196f2f%2Df1e2%2D4f9a%2Da7ac%2D546242c431e2/8c386932f4a2f96c3e95c433e4899ec2/dotnet%2Dsdk%2D8.0.100%2Dosx%2Darm64.pkg](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.100-macos-arm64-installer#:%7E:text=https%3A//download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/cf196f2f%2Df1e2%2D4f9a%2Da7ac%2D546242c431e2/8c386932f4a2f96c3e95c433e4899ec2/dotnet%2Dsdk%2D8.0.100%2Dosx%2Darm64.pkg)